# How can I establish communication between a desktop app and a web app without the need for a backend server?

Tags: web-applications, desktop-application, communication

I aim to create a web application capable of processing data received from a desktop application running locally on each user personal machine. Additionally, I want the web app to be able to send messages to the desktop app.

- no external backend server
- the web app is not running locally

I thought about using API requests and use the local desktop app as a server, but i am not quite sure how to make this work properly (and safely).